# Partial file getting downloaded from Azure Blob storage container- event grid

Tags: azure, function, blob, azure-eventgrid

i am getting Partial file getting downloaded from Azure Blob storage container- event grid. I used event grid approach to get the event of new Blob file uploaded in a container. my function app gets the event, and then i try to download the blob file from the url. problem is i am able to read complete file if file size is 40Kb approx, but it reads incomplete partial file when size exceeds 60 KB.This is done in Azure development environment

here's short snippet to read the file in a stream:

```
var blobRef = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
            string contentReader = string.Empty;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (blobRef.Exists())
                {
                    var blobRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions
                    {
                        ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50),
                        MaximumExecutionTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120)
                    };
                    await blobRef.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream, null,blobRequestOptions,null);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                    {
                        contentReader = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                    }
                }
return contentReader;
```

this code is called from :

```
      var dataTask = BLOBProcessingHelper.GetBlobData(container,url);
                    Task.WaitAll(dataTask);
                    var data = dataTask.Result;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry guys.. this wasn't an issue, actually, we were tracing the azure logs and in logs, we were writing the file data which we read. it turned out that azure log stream has some size limitation to write logs. file was getting read completely. it just that logs didnt write complete data.  :P

cheers :)